# My ASP.NET Core MVC web application does not work on http

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an ASP.NET Core and when the run it in Visual Studio, it opens this url:

```
https://localhost:44392/
```

Now if I try to open this url `http://localhost:44392/`, I will get this error:

> This site can't be reached
> The connection was reset.

I try to comment out this line of code

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

in the `startup.cs` file, but that did not solve the issue.

Any advice?

**EDIT**

The `launchsettings.json` is as follow:-

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59662",
      "sslPort": 44392
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "***: {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what is the question. The site runs on port 44392 on **HTTPS**. Obviously, you can't access this port of HTTP. Do you *want* to access over http for some reason? If yes, then look in `Properties\launchSettings.json`. you will see something like this:

```
 "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5151/",
      "sslPort": 44392
    }
  }
```

In this case you can access your site over `http://localhost:5151/`, but depending on the `UseHttpsRedirection()` it may redirect to HTTPS anyway.

If that's *not* what you are asking - please elaborate

**UPDATE**: So, with `launchsetting.json` the way you have it - does this answer your question? you should be able to access your site `http://localhost:59662` assuming you run through IIS

Comment: It says `"sslPort": 44392` not 59662.

Comment: @Patrick - you lost me... does it contradict anything I wrote? :O

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to set it when you setup the app by unchecking the "configure for HTTPS" box see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

another option is to connect to HTTPS and trust the VS localhost certificate as written [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos).